# Replace discontinued evap line?

Tags: volvo, evap, 850, vacuum-hoses

My evap line got damaged and the part has been discontinued by Volvo (its a 1996 850 model). The particular hose is the one that runs across the frame in the front.

Can this line be replaced with a generic rubber hose?

Answer (score 3):

Yup, you can replace it with generic hose.

Answer (score 1):

Any competent refrigeration engineer / shop can sort a suitable replacement and they will be able to match fittings etc.